# Have properties of base class serialize when serializing derived class

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, serialization

I have a base class with a few properties:

```
    // must include any derived classes here as known types or else they will throw errors on serialization
[KnownType(typeof(CollaborationEventMeasureDistance))]
[DataContract]
public partial class CollaborationEvent
{
    public bool HasBeenTransported { get; set; }
    public Guid MessageBoxGuid { get; set; } 

    public CollaborationEvent()
    {
        HasBeenTransported = false;
    }

}
```

And a derived class with some properties of its own:

```
    public class CollaborationEventMeasureDistance : CollaborationEvent
{
    public Geometry Geometry { get; set; }
}
```

When I serialize the derived class, all of its properties are serialized, but the properties it inherits from the base class are not:

```
<CollaborationEvent i:type="CollaborationEventMeasureDistance">
  <Geometry xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry"
  i:type="d4p1:Polyline">
    <d4p1:spatialReference>
      <d4p1:wkid>26910</d4p1:wkid>
    </d4p1:spatialReference>
    <d4p1:paths>
      <d4p1:points>
        <d4p1:point>
          <d4p1:spatialReference>
            <d4p1:wkid>26910</d4p1:wkid>
          </d4p1:spatialReference>
          <d4p1:x>460892.23924271885</d4p1:x>
          <d4p1:y>5367682.5572773879</d4p1:y>
        </d4p1:point>
        <d4p1:point>
          <d4p1:spatialReference i:nil="true" />
          <d4p1:x>461001.35841108358</d4p1:x>
          <d4p1:y>5367648.5755294543</d4p1:y>
        </d4p1:point>
      </d4p1:points>
    </d4p1:paths>
  </Geometry>
</CollaborationEvent>
```

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

I expect my XML to look more like:

```
    <CollaborationEvent i:type="CollaborationEventMeasureDistance">
  <HasBeenTransported>True</HasBeenTransported>
  <MessageBoxGuid>blah</MessageBoxGuid>
  <Geometry xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry"
  i:type="d4p1:Polyline">
    <d4p1:spatialReference>
      <d4p1:wkid>26910</d4p1:wkid>
    </d4p1:spatialReference>
    <d4p1:paths>
      <d4p1:points>
        <d4p1:point>
          <d4p1:spatialReference>
            <d4p1:wkid>26910</d4p1:wkid>
          </d4p1:spatialReference>
          <d4p1:x>460892.23924271885</d4p1:x>
          <d4p1:y>5367682.5572773879</d4p1:y>
        </d4p1:point>
        <d4p1:point>
          <d4p1:spatialReference i:nil="true" />
          <d4p1:x>461001.35841108358</d4p1:x>
          <d4p1:y>5367648.5755294543</d4p1:y>
        </d4p1:point>
      </d4p1:points>
    </d4p1:paths>
  </Geometry>
</CollaborationEvent>
```

Thanks

Comment: Are they set at the time of serialization?

Comment: Can we see your serialization code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your Geometry class is serializable, try something like this:

```
[DataContract, Serializable]
public class CollaborationEventMeasureDistance : CollaborationEvent  
{  
    [DataMember]
    public Geometry Geometry { get; set; }  
} 

[KnownType(typeof(CollaborationEventMeasureDistance))] 
[DataContract, Serializable]
public partial class CollaborationEvent 
{ 
    [DataMember]
    public bool HasBeenTransported { get; set; } 
    [DataMember]
    public Guid MessageBoxGuid { get; set; }  

    public CollaborationEvent() 
    { 
        HasBeenTransported = false; 
    } 

}
```

Comment: Thanks Tyler. I didn't think I needed any more "syntactic sugar" on the properties, because the derived class' properties were serializing without it. But the [DataMember] attribute sure enough cleared it up. Cheers.